# Calculation gives different results

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to calculate a formula in Android:

```
percent = absence/(week*(37/period))*100;
```

The value for `absence` is `4`, week is `2`, and period is `2`. `percent` returns `11.111111`.

But if I do the same in Excel with formula `4/(2*(37/2))*100`, it returns `10.81`.

Can anyone explain me what might be wrong?

Comment: Because integer division.

Comment: add the declaration of your variables, but it's most likely they are ints

Comment: @AndrewL Yes, one of the variable (period) was integer because they only holds 1 or 2. Care to explain why this works this way in coding when the rest are Double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of integer division.

> The value for absence is 4, week is 2, and period is 2. percent returns 11.111111.

This is because 37 / 2 is 18.5, and the fractional part is thrown out because of integer division. That gives 18, which multiplied by 2 is 36. Next we divide 4 by 36, which is 0.111... That multiplied by 100 is 11.111....

> But if I do the same in Excel with formula 4/(2*(37/2))*100, it returns 10.81.

This is because Excel doesn't use integer division. 37 / 2 is 18.5, 18.5 * 2 is 37. 4 / 37 is 0.108108108... Thus multiplying by 100 gives approximately 10.81.

---

**Explanation**

The reason it's doing integer division is because you have an integer `period`. Java sees that there are two integers and are being divided so it uses integer division. This causes all fractional parts to be erased, meaning the 0.5 from 18.5 resulting from 37 /  2 is removed, making the results different.

**Fix**

You can 'fix' this by making at least one of the operands in the division float or double:

```
double percent = absence/(week*((double) 37/period))*100;
```

What this will do is achieve floating-point division giving 10.8108...

Answer (score 0):

Declare all of the variables as `double` and it will work as you expect:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double period = 2;
        double absence = 4;
        double week = 2;
        double percent = absence /(week *(37/period ))*100;
        System.out.println("percent: " + percent);
    }
```

Gives the output:

`percent: 10.81081081081081`

If your `period` variable is declared as an `int`, your output will change to:

`percent: 11.11111111111111`

This is becuase you're losing precision due to rounding down when you divide 37 by the `int` `period`. If you change it to `double`, it will give you the expected result.